# javascript/http post request without redirecting to the website

Tags: javascript, html, post, get

I am trying to allow users to log into a different/external website that allows Cross-Origin Resource Sharing.

This is my html for password and username:

```
<form action="http:...../login/login.cfm" method="post"> 
<input type="text" placeholder="username" id="username" name="username" ><br>
<input type="password" placeholder="password" id="password" name="password">
<button onclick= "test()">Save & Enter</button>
</form>
```

This does log you in to the site but it also redirects you to the page that opens up after you log in. How do I just log the user in and then GET a string from a web page.

Also I could use the get request to validate the password because if it cannot GET the information then the person entered the wrong username or password.

So how do a I do a password and username post without redirecting to the site?
PLEASE HELP.
(This is all client side, Javascript, jquery, and html only. No php.)

```
<form> 
<input type="text" placeholder="username" id="username" name="username" ><br>
<input type="password" placeholder="password" id="password" name="password">
<button onclick= "test()">Save & Enter</button>
</form> 
<script>
var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
var password = document.getElementById("password ").value;
$.post( "http://.../login/login.cfm", { name: username, password: password })
  .done(function( data ) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
  });
</script>
```

This does not work.

Here is an example:

```
username=daniel&password=password
```

Comment: what does your login page `"http://.../login/login.cfm"` expects, and what is response? You need to know how your login mechanism works

Comment: example username=daniel&password=password

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<form> 
    <input type="text" placeholder="username" id="username" name="username" ><br />
    <input type="password" placeholder="password" id="password" name="password">
    <button onclick="test(); return false;">Save &amp; Enter</button>
</form> 
<script>
function test() {
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password ").value;
    $.post( "http://.../login/login.cfm", { name: username, password: password })   
      .done(function( data ) {
        alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
    });
}
</script>
```